# ArcPy if part of string not in field, then delete row

Tags: arcpy, python, cursor

I am able to use UpdateCursor to find and delete rows if a field contains part of a string (code below works). Now I want to do the opposite--if part of this string is *not in* my field, I want to delete the row. Is there a "not_in" function/syntax?

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(mySHP, ['OID@', 'Comments']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if 'this phrase' in row[1]:
            cursor.deleteRow()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either add a `not` to the if statement:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(mySHP, ['OID@', 'Comments']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if 'this phrase' not in row[1]:
            cursor.deleteRow()
```

or you could add an else block:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(mySHP, ['OID@', 'Comments']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if 'this phrase' in row[1]:
            pass
        else:
            cursor.deleteRow()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a where clause to limit the rows returned by the cursor. This should be faster since not all rows are read by the cursor.

```
import arcpy

mySHP = r'C:\shapefile.shp'
commentfield = 'Comments'
sql = """{0} NOT LIKE '%this frase%'""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(mySHP,commentfield))

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(mySHP, commentfield, sql) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        cursor.deleteRow(row)
```